# Android 11 - Audio on Pixel 3a wired headphones very quiet

Tags: audio, headphones, volume, android-11

I've just updated my Pixel 3a to Android 11 beta

[image]

and listening audio from Youtube using the original device's headphones

I noticed that, even with media volume set to maximum,

the sound is much more quieter than before.

I tried to disable absolute volume, w/o any result.

Any workaround? (I'm not gonna root my phone)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but I have the same issue. I installed a volume booster and it seems to be doing the trick just fine. There are a number of them on google play, not sure what the best is.